# Hide a submit button in IE7 with CSS

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

I have a submit button with a markup like this:

```
<li class="button"><div class="button">
<input type="submit" name="sign_in" id="sign_in" value="Prihlásiť" class="input-submit" /></div></li>
```

I want to hide it so it's not visible.

I did this:

```
.button, input.input-submit {
    height: 0;
    line-height: 0;
    border: 0;
}
```

And that works in Firefox and IE8. But in IE7 there is still a space taken by the button even though it's not visible (so there is like a 20px gap).

What to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don´t know if you use a reset style-sheet, so you could use:

```
.button, input.input-submit {
    height: 0;
    border: none;
    width: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

If that doesn´t do it, it could be because it is an inline element, so you try to add:

```
display: inline-block;
```

[More about inline-block](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html#inlineblock)

**Edit:** As an afterthought, it seems to me you only need to hide the **li**, all content inside the li will be automatically hidden as well but you might have to give the li a:

```
overflow: hidden;
```

Comment: I also added `position:fixed` and `background:none` because otherwise it still renders a small gray square that takes up a couple pixels in the layout.

Answer (score 0):

```
.button, input.input-submit {
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: First of all this has the same problem (doesn't work properly in IE7). 2) I don't wanna use display: none because of screen readers.

Comment: Unusual that it doesn't work in IE - should do... What about positioning it miles off the page:
    .button, input.input-submit {
      position:relative; left:-2000px;
     }